# Cloudfoundry: Deploying a standalone application using Spring and RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a standalone application to CloudFoundry. I am using a Spring `ApplicationContext` in my `main`-method to initialize Spring and I have a simple Bean to handle the messaging with RabbitMQ.

In the `spring.xml` I have configured RabbitMQ and in the pom file I have added the necessary dependencies for `cglib-nodep`, `spring-rabbit` and `cloudfoundry-runtime`. I am further more using the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin to create a single jar file which contains all the libraries, and I then deploy it to cloudfoundry with the `vmc`-tool.

When I deploy the `jar`-file to CloudFoundry I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]

Offending resource: class path resource [spring.xml]

[stacktrace ommited]
```

Here is my `spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd
        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring
        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.7.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />

    <!-- Obtain a connection to the RabbitMQ via cloudfoundry-runtime: -->
    <cloud:rabbit-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/>

    <!-- Set up the AmqpTemplate/RabbitTemplate: -->
    <rabbit:template connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <!-- Request that queues, exchanges and bindings be automatically
         declared on the broker: -->
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <!-- Declare the "messages" queue: -->
    <rabbit:queue name="messages" durable="true"/>
</beans>
```

And the configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>at.ac.tuwien.infosys.dse2013s.group17.allocator.ui.StartUpAllocator</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What could be the reason for the above error? Is there something wrong with how I configured the maven-assembly-plugin, or is there really a problem in the spring.xml?

**Update**

I was able to solve the error, by adding the spring-context dependency to my root pom as a managed dependency and then referencing it from my module without the version element. Now I am getting the same error but this time the Exception complains about the http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]** I recommend to take a look at the [cf-maven-plugin](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client/tree/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin#deploying-a-stand-alone-spring-application), which makes it much easier to deploy to CloudFoundry, so its no longer needed to work with the vmc tool directly. The GitHub page explains both howto deploy **normal** and **standalone** applications with this plugin, and also explains to use the appassembler-maven-plugin for standalone applications. This [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/09/22/rapid-cloud-foundry-deployments-with-maven/) is also useful to get started.
**[/Update]**

It turned out I was deploying the application in a wrong way to CloudFoundry. I was using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, which unpacked the class files of all dependencies into the jar file. In fact I had to use the `appassembler-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.1</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>assemble</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <assembledirectory>target</assembledirectory>
                 <programs>
                     <program>
                         <mainClass>my.package.myclass</mainClass>
                     </program>
                 </programs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I then deployed the application to CloudFoundry like this from the the `target/` folder

```
vmc push <myappname> --path=appassembler
```

As run command I needed to choose the name of the run script in the `appassembler/bin` folder. For example `bin/start-up-myapp`.